# solr 4.1 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: first position increment must be > 0 (got 0)

Tags: search, solr, indexing

all!
After i update my solr version to 4.1, there is a such error when rebuild index:

```
Warning: Error creating document : SolrInputDocument[dop_pos_state=, dop_country=, dop_first_name_onlySort=Rick, dop_first_name=Rick, dop_sync_flag=true, dop_orgid=1522402, dop_last_name=King, dop_last_name_onlySort=King, dop_invite_flag=true, dop_name=Rick King, dop_metro_area=, dop_create_date=2012-12-15 08:53:55.0, dop_address=Greater Boston Area, dop_job_level=1, dop_id=343218, dop_title=at A & J Engineering Inc., dop_update_date=2013-02-19 09:38:38.0, dop_metromap_id=210, dop_facebook_linked=0, dop_linkedin_linked=0, dop_crunchBase_linked=0, dop_twitter_linked=0] 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: first position increment must be > 0 (got 0)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverterPerField.processFields(DocInverterPerField.java:125)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.processDocument(DocFieldProcessor.java:306)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:250)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:376)
```

When i delete the field dop_title (which is "at A & J Engineering Corp." ) in schema.xml, it works fine. The dop_title's analyzer is below:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then I put in solr's analysis page, the result is:
[image]

How did this happen and in which way can i avoid this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: When i delete the WordDelimiterFilterFactory, it works fine again, so is this the problem? WordDelimiterFilterFactory is not compatible with solr 4.1？

Comment: I put the WordDelimiterFilterFactory before the StopFilterFactory, it works fine too. So I guess maybe WordDelimiterFilterFactory can't process null field.

Comment: Guess that must be the issue! The examples and use cases I have come across with WordDelimiterFilterFactory have always used it immediately after the WhitespaceTokenizerFactory, so never ran into this. Good to know.

Comment: BTW, dont use real data for posts :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ongoing migration from stream-based to graph-based processing of tokens. This has uncovered some strange edge-cases in Solr 4.1. It looks like yours is one of those (a regression). You can open [an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR) if you want and somebody will look at it.

In a meanwhile, you may find it useful to know that if you tick the little "Verbose Output" button on the right side of the analysis page, it shows a lot more information about each step in the pipeline, including position values. That could help you to debug this issue faster and/or help to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I will try "Verbose Output" :-)